# ASP.Net Context.RewritePath does not work when original URL contains query string

Tags: asp.net, rewritepath

I am writing IHttpModule to allow friendly URL access to our one of the detail page. When user is trying to access detail page using http://xyx.com/hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx page, re-write rule is going to applied in IHttpModule's OnBeginRequest method.

Here, I wrote to change path to "~/DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx" using Context.RewritePath("~/DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx", "", "Code=123"), where 123 is code taken from Original URL.

Now if original URL does not contain any query string, Detail page is getting invoked. But when user is trying to access http://xyz.com/hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?show=advance then re-write code will be executed as `Context.RewritePath("~/DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx", "", "Code=123&show=advance")`. Here we are getting an error saying "/hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx" page does not existing.

Before & After Calling "`Context.RewritePath`" method, I have taken details from `Context.Request` object that is given below. Both looks perfect and same if there is no Query string in original URL. But when Original URL contains query string, Inside "Context_Error" (an event to listen any error for this request execution) method, when getting `Server.GetLastError()` says "/hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx" page does not existing.

Please refer below trace detail from `Context.Request` object. Your help/inputs are welcome as i have spent 8 hrs already without any positive result.

**---------------------------
Before - RewritePath Call
---------------------------**

RawUrl :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?a=b

AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath :  - ~/Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

CurrentExecutionFilePath :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

Params :  - a=b&__utma=221736730.1213284380.1356606190.1356674469.1356687004.4.....(Windows+NT+5.1%3b+rv%3a7.0.1)+Gecko%2f20100101+Firefox%2f7.0.1

Path :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

PhysicalPath :  - D:\AppRoot\Hotels\161\hotel-name.aspx

Url :  - http://xyz.com/Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?a=b

**---------------------------
After - RewritePath Call
---------------------------**

RawUrl :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?a=b

AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath :  - ~/DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx

CurrentExecutionFilePath :  - /DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx

Params :  - Code=123&a=b&__utma=221736730.1213284380.1356606190.1356674469.1356687004.4.....(Windows+NT+5.1%3b+rv%3a7.0.1)+Gecko%2f20100101+Firefox%2f7.0.1

Path :  - /DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx

PhysicalPath :  - D:\AppRoot\DetailPages\DetailPage.aspx

Url :  - http://xyz.com/DetailPages/DetailPage.aspx?Code=123&a=b

**---`Server.GetLastError` - Trace - Inside IHttpModule's Error Event--**

RawUrl :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?a=b

AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath :  - ~/Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

CurrentExecutionFilePath :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

Params :  - a=b&__utma=221736730.1213284380.1356606190.1356674469.1356687004.4....(Windows+NT+5.1%3b+rv%3a7.0.1)+Gecko%2f20100101+Firefox%2f7.0.1

Path :  - /Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx

PhysicalPath :  - D:\AppRoot\Hotels\161\hotel-name.aspx

Url :  - http://xyz.com/Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx?a=b

**Error Message** 
The file '/Hotels/123/hotel-name.aspx' does not exist.

**Stack Trace**

```
at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Can anyone find out what could be an issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the rewrite module provided by Microsoft? http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Is that on IIS ? If so what version ?

Comment: This is on IIS 5.5 (Win XP) and going to deploy on IIS7. My concern here is, why it is not working when Original URL contains Query String but working when no query string. If i solve this problem, I am done for what i need. But I will check Inbuilt IIS rewrite module. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another IHttpModule changing URL when found Query String in Original URL. Hence I get what I need.

Thank you all for your kind suggestions and interest.